# Как закрыть меню по клику на кнопку открытия

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var filter = function () {
    var $hideElement = $('.services-filter__nav');
    $('.services-filter__open').on('click', function(){
        $hideElement.addClass('services-filter__nav-opend');
    });
    $('.services-nav__item').on('click', function(){
        $hideElement.removeClass('services-filter__nav-opend');
    });
};
```

Вот такой скрипт, сделал чтоб меню закрывалось по клику на пункт меня. Но оно теперь не закрывается по клику на саму кнопку открытия (services-filter__open)

Answer (score 0):

Создай переменную, в которой будешь хранить открыто меню или закрыто.
Например:

```
var statusMenu = false; // меню закрыто

if(statusMenu == false) {
   // Открываем меню
} else {
   // закрываем.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете переключать класс по клику:

```
$(".services-filter__open").click(function () {
  $hideElement.toggleClass("services-filter__nav-opend");
});
```